# How to remove XML version from php://input

Tags: php, xml, fopen

We have a PHP script that receives XML data in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<job>
 <job_reference>123</job_reference>
 <job_description>Lorem ipsum.</job_description>
 <job_title>IT Manager</job_title>
 etc...
</job>
```

The script currently writes this to a file, replacing the existing data. However we now need it to append to the existing data, but obviously we can only have one occurance of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` or the XML file will be invalid. I know I need to change the fopen mode from 'w' to 'a', but how would I strip out the XML version line from the `$xml`. The current code is:

```
<?php
  $xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $data = $xml;
  $file = fopen( 'broadbeantesttest.xml', "w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
  // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
  if (fwrite($file, $xml) === FALSE) {
      echo "Cannot write to file ($file)";
      exit;
  }
  fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Note that XML file can have only one root element, so you cannot simply append contents to it.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that and used str_replace to remove `</jobs>` from the end of the file and then add it back in along with the new xml data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just remove it with [`str_replace()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$xmlString = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '', $xmlString);
file_put_contents("broadbeantesttest.xml", $xmlString, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform it in a DOMdocument and return it to XML format;

```
$temp_xml = new DOMDocument();
$temp_xml->loadXML($your_xml);
$your_xml = $t_xml->saveXML($temp_xml->documentElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my final code in the end, the only thing I might change is limiting the number of Jobs that can be included, but we don't anticipate there being a huge number:

```
<?php
   $new = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $new = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '', $new);
   $filename = "broadbean.xml";
   $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
   $old = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
   $old = str_replace('</jobs>', '', $old);
   $jobs = '</jobs>';
   $xml = $old . $new . "\r" . $jobs;
   $data = $xml;

   // Write XML File and update
   $file = fopen( 'broadbean.xml', "w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
   // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($file, $xml) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($file)";
        exit;
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is XML you should use an XML API to handle it. This will make sure you're reading and writing valid XML. It will take care of charsets/encodings, too.

An XML can only have a single document element node. Append the request data will generate an XML fragment, not an XML document. You need to have something like `jobs` on the top level.

The XML file could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jobs>
  <job>
   <job_reference>123</job_reference>
   <job_title>IT Manager</job_title>
  </job>
</jobs>
```

The XML in the request body contains only a single `job` so it can be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<job>
 <job_reference>456</job_reference>
 <job_title>Programmer</job_title>
</job>
```

You need to load both documents and import the `job` element from the request data into the target document. Append it to the `jobs` element and save it.

```
$storage = new DOMDocument();
$storage->load($fileName);

$input = new DOMDocument();
$input->loadXml(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$storage->documentElement->appendChild(
  $storage->importNode($input->documentElement, TRUE)
);

$storage->save($fileName);
```